# How to write Con expression in Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, con, error-010240, rusle

I want to calculate S factor for USLE model when I tried to run my expression, I met a problem.

```
Con("Slope_Fill_sl" <=5 ,10.8*Sin("Slope_Fill_sl" +0.03 )
```

Can anyone tell me which part I did wrong？

[image]

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to save a raster layer to a database with a comma in the name of the file.  Remove the comma from your file name.
See this link for naming conventions in ArcGIS Pro.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/output-raster-formats-and-names.htm